# Multiple has_paper_trail in a model, one for :create e another one for :update

Tags: paper-trail-gem

I have the situation when in the :create scenario I need to use the :if checking one field but when in the :update or :touch scenario I need to use the :if for another field (ignoring the field checked when :create).

So, I'm trying to do this.

```ruby
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail if: Proc.new { |mymodel| mymodel.whodunnit.present? }, 
    on: [:create]
  has_paper_trail if: Proc.new { |mymodel| mymodel.status.present? }, 
    on: [:update, :touch]

  before_create { 
    PaperTrail.request.whodunnit = whodunnit if whodunnit.present? 
  }

  attr_accessor :whodunnit
end
```

But it is not working, what is the correct way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Re: "it is not working" can you please elaborate? Do you get an error? If so, please include the relevant parts of the stack trace. I'm guessing you're getting a `NoMethodError` at `mymodel.whodunnit` but it's hard to help based on guesses.